# Add an Application User to property-file of my wildfly server out of java ee 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, ejb, wildfly

i am developing an web application with java ee 7 on a wildfly application server (EJB, JSF, JPA, ...). To protect subpages for unauthorized access, i created security constraints and roles (Just two: Admin and User) on my web.xml - and they work fine with the users i created manually on the add-user.bat on wildfly/bin.

My question is: how is it possible to save new usernames and passwords (role should be always 'user') out of the java web application to be saved in the property file 'application-users'?

Later - i want to create a session for a cart after successfully authorization of the users with the credentials of the application-users file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security-wise the web application should not be able to have write access to the application-users.properties file. If you need to create users from your application, help yourself by choosing a proper store for your user database (MySql, LDAP or even H2 which should be fine for development).

Alternatively, if you really want to use a property file, define one outside the JBoss installation directory (somewhere in /var/data/my-app). That way you can't accidentally corrupt your JBoss setup. Copy the security domain configuration which references the application-users.properties and change the file path to your own users property file.